# Tag burnination: [logic]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[logic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) currently has 17 questions.  I don't see what they have in common.  There is no tag wiki to clarify what it means or when it should be applied.

Please either upvote the "Yes" answer, upvote the "No" answer, or propose an alternative course of action as another answer.

Comment: If the community agrees to burninate this tag, I'll contact SE to have it taken out right away (no mass retagging on our part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[logic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) has done the [logic]al thing and submitted itself to Trogdor for burnination.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Upvote this if you agree with the proposal to abolish the [logic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) tag.  (Optionally add your reason as a comment.)

Comment: Looks like "logic" is used as a buzzword on those 17 questions. On most of the 17, it could be "algorithm" too. I see only a few that are centered around logical operators. The thing is, "logic" is a wide term that casually refers to  what the program does - "business logic". Let it burn.

Comment: @retailcoder Actually, [tag:algorithm] is overused too. However, there _are_ some questions where the algorithm itself is an interesting topic of discussion, so I'll leave that mess alone for now.

Comment: @200_success: I was thinking that, too.  [algorithm] can always be cleaned out, but it doesn't have to happen now.

Comment: [And it burns burns burns...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIBTg7q9oNc)

Answer (score 0):

Upvote this if you wish to keep [logic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) tag.  (Optionally add your reason as a comment.)